# How to determine a PC's IP v6 address

Tags: windows, ip, ipv6

How can you determine a PC's `IP v6` address ?

I have 2 machines, and if I do an `ipconfig` on one, I get ...

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::784a:3ddb:df51:9301%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.75
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
```

But if I try to ping the target machine from another machine with ...

```
ping -6 fe80::784a:3ddb:df51:9301%12
```

I get `Destination unavailable`

However if I ping the target machines name ...

```
ping -6 vmvs2010
```

I get a successful response ...

```
>ping -6 vmvs2010

Pinging vmVS2010 [fe80::784a:3ddb:df51:9301%16] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::784a:3ddb:df51:9301%16: time=4ms
Reply from fe80::784a:3ddb:df51:9301%16: time=3ms
```

So I can see the `%12` value needs to be `%16`, but how can I determine this in advance ?

Comment: Why are you trying to ping your local IPv6 address exactly?

Comment: In this case I have my laptop and two virtual machines, one Win2008, the other Win2003. The Win2008 can browse a website on my laptop's IIS, but the Win2003 virtual can't find the site ... but it can ping and access the admin share on the laptop. Only difference seems to be the Win2003 doesn't have IPv6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the % suffix all together.

Comment: How is this the answer? This won't work because link-local scope addresses (ones that start with `fe80::`) need to be qualified with an interface. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746082/ipv6-link-local-address-format/5748034#5748034). The problem is that specifying `%12` causes the packets to go out the LAN interface. Looks like `%16` is an interface for the VM being pinged.